# Can you use Wemo Smart Switches Long Press to “Fake” a 3-Way Set Up?

Tags: switch, dimmer-switch, smart-switch

I have many Wemo smart switches, smart dimmers and even two of their 3-way switches.

However, I don’t have a neutral wire for the 3-way switches, so they’re out.

But I have hooked up some other smart switches and smart dimmers (still talking Wemo here), and after setting them up see that they’re able to do much more than just control the light(s) they’re wired to. For example, you can “long press” and that can control any other Wemo in the house.

So, keeping in mind that the wiring for the three way locations is “3-way” wired, can I just ignore the red wire, install smart switches in these locations, and then set them to use “normal press” as on/off and “long press” for “turn both Wemo’s on/off” to sort of fake a 3-way switch?

[image: Wiring in 3-way receptacle space]

Comment: Is this switch one which is required by Code to satisfy the minimum requirements to have an operable light switch in a room?

Comment: There are four other switches controlling multiple other lights in the room that this switch is in. This switch controls a light at the top of the stairs, as would the second switch I’m hoping to have working in unison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer here — specifically for Wemo — is to wire up the one switch which has a ground to the light, and then use a Wemo stage scene controller at the other “3-way” switch. This will allow the stage scene controller to control the main switch and create what is essentially a 3-way switch.